# firebase database set funtion does not work

Tags: javascript, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

This is my code.here set function does not work(value is not updated in firebase database) and no error shown in console.please help me.

```
var config = {
apiKey: '************************************',
authDomain: 'my-app.firebaseapp.com',
databaseURL: 'https://my-app.firebaseio.com',
storageBucket: 'gs://my-app.appspot.com'
};
firebase.initializeApp(config);

var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
rootRef.set({
'like':'5'
});
```

firebase database rules as follows

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true,
    "learning": {
  "mngmt_quote":
  {

  },
  "Author":{

  }
 }
 }
 }
```

I have tried many methods found in internet.no solution found.please help me

Comment: Your code runs fine for me. Have you imported firebase?

Comment: yes import statement is as follows''<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/3.7.4/firebase.js"></script>"

Comment: That is required in index.html file. In your .js file you need to require/import firebase first like var firebase = require("firebase");

Comment: you mean firebase coding is not in pure javascript .is it in node js

Comment: You better follow these https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup and https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/start links.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this and see if what message you get.

```
    var rootRef = firebase.database().ref();
                rootRef.set({
                        like: '5'
                    }).then(success => {
                            console.log('success',success);
                        },
                        error => {
                            console.log('error',error);
                        }
                    );
```

Comment: This is because your code doesn't get executed at any time.

Comment: I have tried console output below that.Console output is got

Comment: Okay. Try putting your code in try-catch block. Put console in catch block , see if you get any error. Also put that initializeApp() in try block.